# MySQL - Get result for root node for a table containing end node items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which lists all the employees in an org with their immediate parent.

| id | name | parent | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | D | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | E | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | F | 4 | 3 |
| 7 | E | 5 | 4 |
| 8 | F | 6 | 4 |

I have another table which lists actions by last node employees:

| id | action | type | emp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Action Name | 0 | 7 |
| 2 | Action Name | 0 | 8 |
| 3 | Action Name | 1 | 7 |
| 4 | Action Name | 2 | 7 |
| 5 | Action Name | 3 | 8 |
| 6 | Action Name | 4 | 8 |
| 7 | Action Name | 5 | 7 |
| 8 | Action Name | 6 | 8 |

I need to show a hierarchical view of the action count. As evident above, all the actions are created by either employee with an id of 7 or 8. I need to show the number of actions by employees with type 1 based on their own actions or by any sub down the chain.

At the moment, I pull the counts on the end node using sql and then use the scripting language to build the hierarchy bottom up.

Is there a better way to achive this with SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Have a look at these questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/rchical-queries-in-mysql , https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins

Comment: What version are you using, and what would the result look like? Also, if the suggestions above don't solve your problem, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: At the very least, your question needs to show the results you want.  Being explicit about the version of MySQL is also helpful.